# Deactivate Homeshare

Tags: itunes

I have a new computer and want to use itunes homeshare. I have found that there are already 5 computers  sharing , of which I know 3 aren't being used (scrapped) so i can't just log on to them , to deactivate them. Can i do this remotely ??

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1420) Apple Support article you can do it from your account however the caveat is you need to de-authorize all of them at once.

> If you find you have reached 5 authorizations, you can reset your authorization count by clicking Deauthorize All in the Account Information screen.

Step by step instructions are available in the linked article. Also note the following:

> **Note:** You may only use this feature once per year. The Deauthorize All button will not appear if you have fewer than 5 authorized computers, or if you have used this option within the last 12 months. If you need assistance on using this feature please contact iTunes Store support via email.